# Specifying properties returned from API in client

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to limit the amount of properties that are returned from my REST api built in dotnet core. When accessing resources the client only needs specific subsets of the data returned from the api. What is a good way to tell the api which properties the client wants returned?

My initial thought would be to add query parameters to the endpoint like this:

http://www.restapi.com/v1/resource?fields=id,name,type

But I am not sure the best way to implement this in the api so that it is reusable and clean.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you usually don't want to return your full domain model or data model over your web API. Usually you define a custom model type for this purpose, which you can also decorate with attributes for model binding and model validation, if desired.

If you want the client to be able to determine what properties it gets, you can return an anonymous type built for this purpose, or perhaps have several DTO types predefined that the client's parameters result in.